# Multiple VPN tunnels between two hosts to increase bandwidth

Tags: 14.04, vpn, webserver, tunnel

I set up VPN tunnel between my web server and a proxy server to by pass some restrictions such as the country firewall.

The VPN tunnel works well. But when too many requests to my server, all the HTTP request trans between the single tunnel.

Though I've remove my server side restriction for each IP， but when the traffic is heavy, the page loads very slowly. So I want to know how to solve this.

Now I try to set up multi tunnels, but I googles a while, with no progress.

Comment: - what VPN  software are you runnning?

Comment: pptpd  or openvpn

Answer (score 3):

In the common case a bandwidth problem won't be solved by adding more tunnels.

If you have traffic that is compressible and option in openvpn is adding:

> comp-lzo

on each VPN endpoints server.conf
This can decrease bandwidth usage by compressing data before sending it through the tunnel.

you can read more about it in the [man page](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/manuals/65-openvpn-20x-manpage.html)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have rather bandwidth problem. The multi routing will not solve your problem, as you would need to setup different routes using iptable rules, which is in my opinion much too complicated. I would check the bandwidth with iperf and increase it. If you still want to increase the number of connections, you may find an answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87990/linux-as-router-with-multiple-internet-providers 
Of course for each connection you will need to set up a different vpn server - vpn client pair and then route the encrypted packets via different routes.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/vpnchains/

This way you would get rid of any extra routes to a virtual machine that might be slowing down your bandwidth speed.

So instead of:

PC <-> OPENVPN1 <-> VM1 <-> OPENVPN2 <-> INTERNET

you will get this:

PC <-> OPENVPN1 <-> OPENVPN2 <-> INTERNET

Though, as others have already said, if you have problems with your first VPN when traffic is heavy, I can't see how adding another tunnel is going to help.

It should also be noted that I have not tested it yet on my machine so I can't tell you for certain that it works.